# Choose columns with sort and cut in a csv with a comma delimiter ',' ignoring data on quotes with comma "text,text"

Tags: command-line, quoting, sort, csv, cut

I am parsing a huge csv file with rows and columns with different parameters. However, some fields contain large descriptions within quotes that contain commas. How can I choose columns with sort and cut ignoring commas within quotes?
I have tried adding quote-comma-quote as a delimiter but I get an error (invalida argument) or excaping the quote with backslash but I also get an error.

```
sort  -k12 -t'","' file
```

or

```
cut -f 12 -d '","' file
```

Example of a row in the file:

```
"GFYZ01001952.1",99.606,"ASTG2327","PREDICTED: kinesin-like protein NACK1 [Elaeis guineensis]","--","centromeric protein E","Kinesin-like protein NACK1 OS=Arabidopsis thaliana GN=NACK1 PE=1 SV=1","Baculovirus polyhedron envelope protein, PEP, C terminus//Autophagy protein Apg6//Basic region leucine zipper//Protein of unknown function (DUF904)",0.005,3.2,3.5,0.00006
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV is a structured document format.  As such, simple text manipulation tools like `cut` (or `sort`, `sed`, or `awk`, unless the data is simple) are inadequate for processing CSV files safely and conveniently (because fields may contain embedded delimiters and newlines).  Instead, it would be best if you were using a CSV-aware processing tool such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`).

The following Miller command parses the file as a header-less CSV file, sorting it numerically ascending by its 12th field:

```bash
mlr --csv -N sort -n 12 file
```

If you have headers in your CSV data, drop the `-N` option and use the header name in place of `12`, e.g.,

```bash
mlr --cvs sort -n pvalue file
```

To extract column 12,

```bash
mlr --csv -N cut -f 12 file
```

To sort *and* cut, and also only get the 10 first results,

```bash
mlr --csv -N sort -n 12 then cut -f 12 then head -n 10 file
```

Again, drop the `-N` and use the field names if you have headers in the input.

---

With the [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) toolkit, you could use `csvsort` to get the same result like so:

```bash
csvsort -H -c 12 file | tail -n +2
```

(the `tail` command removes the headers that `csvsort` generates), or, with headers in the input,

```bash
csvsort -c pvalue file
```

Extracting individual fields with `csvcut`:

```bash
csvcut -H -c 12 file
```

Combined with `csvsort`:

```bash
csvsort -H -c 12 file | csvcut -c 12 | head -n +2
```

Or, with headers,

```bash
csvsort -c pvalue file | csvcut -c pvalue
```

There is no `csvhead` command, so limiting the resutl to 10 records will have to be doen some other way, possibly through `mlr --csv head -n 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for `FPAT` you can identify the fields:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print i " <" $i ">"}' file
1 <"GFYZ01001952.1">
2 <99.606>
3 <"ASTG2327">
4 <"PREDICTED: kinesin-like protein NACK1 [Elaeis guineensis]">
5 <"--">
6 <"centromeric protein E">
7 <"Kinesin-like protein NACK1 OS=Arabidopsis thaliana GN=NACK1 PE=1 SV=1">
8 <"Baculovirus polyhedron envelope protein, PEP, C terminus//Autophagy protein Apg6//Basic region leucine zipper//Protein of unknown function (DUF904)">
9 <0.005>
10 <3.2>
11 <3.5>
12 <0.00006>
```

and while you COULD do the equivalent to your `sort` and `cut` commands internally within gawk, if you really wanted to use those external commands you could use awk to convert the ;-separated \n-terminated records to \n-separated NUL-terminated records and then pipe to any tool that can handle NUL-terminated input, then convert back again if you like, e.g. with GNU awk, cut, and sort:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS='\n' -v ORS='\0' '{$1=$1} 1' file |
    cut -z -f 12 -d $'\n'
0.00006$

$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|("([^"]|"")*")' -v OFS='\n' -v ORS='\0' '{$1=$1} 1' file |
    sort -z -k 12 -t $'\n' |
    awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\n' -F '\n' -v OFS=';' '{$1=$1} 1'
"GFYZ01001952.1";99.606;"ASTG2327";"PREDICTED: kinesin-like protein NACK1 [Elaeis guineensis]";"--";"centromeric protein E";"Kinesin-like protein NACK1 OS=Arabidopsis thaliana GN=NACK1 PE=1 SV=1";"Baculovirus polyhedron envelope protein, PEP, C terminus//Autophagy protein Apg6//Basic region leucine zipper//Protein of unknown function (DUF904)";0.005;3.2;3.5;0.00006
```

See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information.

Comment: thank you very much!